# How can I embed IE in my java applet

Tags: java, browser, cross-browser, cross-platform

How can we embed Internet Explorer into the java application. I am looking for an Open source option to achieve this.

Comment: does it have to be IE or can it be Edge, Chrome, Firefox etc?

Comment: Whats wrong with calling the desktop browser? IE isn't cross platform!